# Input with a href/button img inside

Tags: html, image, css, button, input

I understand how to use `img` inside an `input`, but I don't know how to make the `img` a button or a href. This is what I have so far:

```css
input {
border: none;
padding: 10px;
width: 128px;
border-radius: 5px;

background: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-right-b-128.png') no-repeat;
background-size: 35px 35px;
border:0;
padding-left:30px;
background-color: rgb(18,41,73);
border-color: rgb(18,41,73);
font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="my text"></input>
```

How can I make the `img` arrow as clicked `img`?

Comment: Why would you want to make an input into a link/button?

Comment: So you want the right arrow icon to be a submit button for the form?

Comment: Also, `<input />` elements are self-closing.

Comment: @BenM Yes. this is exactly what i ment

Comment: @Dan this is exactly what i ment

Comment: @user3908497 then why don't just use a link or a button?

Comment: @user3908497 Check my answer below I just added a simple button with some onclick function, convert it to button type=submit and remove onclick to achieve form submit action on clicking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using relative and absolute positioning elements as shown in the below snippet. I used button in this snippet, you change it to link and use href following the same procedure.

```css
input {
border: none;
padding: 10px;
width: 128px;
border-radius: 5px;
border:0;
padding-left:30px;
background-color: rgb(18,41,73);
border-color: rgb(18,41,73);
font-size: 12px;
}
#in_image{
  position:absolute;
  border:none;
  background:none;
  outline:none;
  }
```

```html
<div style="position:relative">
 <button id="in_image" onclick="alert('I am a button')"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-right-b-128.png" width="35" height="35" /></button>
<input type="text" placeholder="my text" />
</div>
```